# Date subtraction in SQL Oracle - trying to find months_between by subtracting "yyyy/mm/dd" and "yyyy/mm"

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to find the difference in months between 2 dates in a SQL oracle table as part of a larger query.

Problem is, date#1 is formatted as "yyyy/mm/dd", and date#2 is formatted as "yyyy/mm". Getting the following error: date format picture ends before converting entire input string.

Here is my query:

```
select count(distinct(aqs.quote_ref_id)), substr(aqs.quote_date,1,7), MONTHS_BETWEEN
       (to_date(qp.policy_effective_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), to_date(qp.property_exp_date, 'yyyy/mm')) as Num_Months
from live.auto_quote_summary aqs join live.quote_profile qp on qp.quote_ref_id = aqs.quote_ref_id
```

etc.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If you do `DESCRIBE live.quote_profile` what is the data type of the `policy_effective_date` and `property_exp_date` columns? If you do a select from that table can you post an example of the data in those columns?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us add to your question, can you post a `select` query result for the two tables `live.auto_quote_summary` and `live.quote_profile`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear. In one of the columns you must have more information than the format model you are using. Either `policy_effective_date` has more than year-month-day (perhaps hh24:mi:ss?) or `property_exp_date` has more than year-month. (Not necessarily in **all** rows but at least in one row.)

To narrow it down, you may try simpler queries. What happens if you `select to_date(policy_effective_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') from live.quote_profile`? Then try the same with the other date column. Find out where you may have data that is not in the format you think it is.

Demo (using SQL*Plus):

```
SQL> select to_date('2017/05', 'yyyy/mm') as dt from dual;

DT
----------
2017-05-01

1 row selected.


SQL> select to_date('2017/05/23', 'yyyy/mm') as dt from dual;
select to_date('2017/05/23', 'yyyy/mm') as dt from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert the first "n" characters that are needed:

```
select count(distinct(aqs.quote_ref_id)), substr(aqs.quote_date, 1, 7),
       months_between(to_date(substr(qp.policy_effective_date, 1, 10), 'yyyy/mm/dd'),
                      to_date(substr(qp.property_exp_date, 1, 7), 'yyyy/mm')
                     ) as Num_Months
from live.auto_quote_summary aqs join
     live.quote_profile qp
     on qp.quote_ref_id = aqs.quote_ref_id
```